# Does anyone know if WordPress has builtin PHP validation functions?

Tags: php, validation, wordpress, forms, function

I am trying to build a form in WordPress and taking advantage of all its built-in functions but I am hard pressed to find any functions that do form validation. I figure those kinds of functions have to exist in WordPress but I couldn't find any because its documentation is sparse and spread out in some respects. Would anyone have any useful links to documentation and tutorials by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 1001 plugins that support contact form validation if that's what your after:

[WordPress Plugins Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=form+validation&sort=)

I don't believe the WordPress code base has any exposed validation functions though. What are you trying to validate? Addresses/emails?